# Google API Client: Container Registry API Python

Tags: python, google-api-client, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

I want to get a list of images in the Google Container Engine using Python, and eventually, start an instance of one of them. I know there's a [gcloud command to list images](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/container/images/list), but is this possible to do using the googleapiclient?

I imagine it would be something like this:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
gce_service =  build('container', 'v1')
# Now what?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For image listing,

Google Container Registry is a Docker Registry API so you probably won't be able to list images through googleapiclient.

Something that uses the Docker Registry API like https://pypi.python.org/pypi/docker-registry-client/1.0  may be worth a try but I have not tried it.